# tess4j Set only to identify numbers and letters

Tags: java, ocr, tess4j

I want to set `tess4j` to only identify numbers and letters

```
Tesseract instance = new Tesseract();
instance.setDatapath("C:\\Users\\qyw\\Desktop\\tessdata");
String s = instance.doOCR(img);
System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
instance.setTessVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
```

See [doc](http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/docs/index.html).